# Regex to detect any of the following characters: ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) < > ‘ ’+ [ ] ? { } | , ; : . “ ~ `

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I'm trying to ensure text box does not contain any of the following characters:

```
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) < > ‘ ’+ [ ] ? { } | , ; : . “ ~ `
```

I'm trying to use regular expression with C# server side code:
something like the below (but I think my regular expression is wrong):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[^\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\+\$#\^\*\(\)\|~]+$");//! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) < > ‘ ’+ [ ] ? { } | , ; : . “ ~ `
if(!Regex.IsMatch(Textbox_Timetable.Text.Trim(), @"^[^\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]+$"))                     
    AddError("Timetable Name must not contain following characters: " + @"\%\/\\\&\?`\,\'\;\:\!\-");
```

Comment: Now the first question is... Are those **ALL** the characaters you dont want or just the characters you have on your keyboard or do you only wish A-Z, 0-9?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Regex.Escape(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you want **readable** code:

```
var escaped = Regex.Escape("!@#$%^&*()<>‘’+[]?{}|,;:.“~`");
var regex = new Regex($"[{escaped}]");
```

That is so much easier than escaping every character manually!

You should drop the `^` and `$` from your regex.  You wanted to detect if *any* of those characters were in the target string, but using those in your regex would mean it would only match if *every* character was from that list.

(This code hasn't been tested, as I dont have a compiler available)

Comment: There is no need to escape these chars in the character class if you put them so: `[][!@#$%^&*()<>‘’+?{}|,;:.“~\`]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. square brackets need to be excaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\+\$#\^\*\(\)\|~]+
```

`^` if is present as first character in square bracket, then it denotes matches any character except following

```
\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\+\$#\^\*\(\)\|~]
```

use this

```
^[\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\+\$#\^\*\(\)\|~^@]+` or `^[\^\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\+\$#\^\*\(\)\|~@]+
```

to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab any char you want `` [!@#$%^&*()<>‘’+[]?{}|,;:.“~`] `` and that's your regex. Then simple inversion using  !` is all you nead to check if input is vald.